# el.style.width vs el.offsetWidth

Tags: javascript

Difference between `document.getElementbyId("").style.width` and `document.getElementbyId("").offsetWidth`

Answer (score 0):

> Typically, an element's offsetWidth is a measurement which includes
>   the element borders, the element horizontal padding, the element
>   vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element CSS
>   width.

source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth

Comment: if i use document.getElementbyId("").style.width to find width of table i'm getting " " as answer i'm not getting width...why is that so

Comment: did you assign the width style property in css?

Comment: no...i want to get width of table dynamically....i have not set width of table using css or html...but i have made sure data is in table

Comment: if you didnt set the width then how you can get it ??

Comment: yes you are right now :). please accept the answer If my answer helped you :)